# Using IIS / ARR, Can I tell a site to use a specific server farm cluster?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I currently have an IIS/ARR server setup with a single Server Farm Cluster defined that includes 3 servers and I have one site using that cluster.

I am going to add a new site to the server with a 2nd IP to support another SSL certificate.

I setup the site without SSL and the balance works just fine with the new site. But I am concerned that I will screw something up when I add in the 2nd IP on all the servers.

I think I need to add a new server farm cluster with the 3 new IPs for this new site - how do I tell the IIS/ARR server that the 2nd site should only use the new server farm cluster - and that the current site should use the current cluster?

This is a production system, so I really don't want to blow everything up while I do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the global rewrite rules, where you setup the redirection to one of the farms, you can add a condition to inspect the {INSTANCE_ID}.

The instance Id would be the Id of the instance where the request comes in and no the instance part of the Farm. [image]

Comment: I have since moved off this project, and this system was transitioned to a new server farm. This looks like it would solve the issue though, I cannot test it myself, but thanks for the direction if I need it in the future!